# Insert new line breaks in findstr output

Tags: for-loop, replace, output, newline, findstr

I'd like to insert a new line before a specific string at the findstr output.

Currently I've a Windows batch script with the following FINDSTR command...

```
for %%i in (*.mkv) do "c:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" -i -F json "%%i" | findstr -i "id type codec language" | findstr /v "codec_private_data packetizer container_type is_providing_timestamps identification_format_version codec_private_length codec_id uid"
```

...which produces the following output...

"type": "Matroska"
     "codec": "MPEG-4p10/AVC/h.264",
     "id": 0,
       "language": "und",
     "type": "video"
     "codec": "DTS",
     "id": 1,
       "language": "eng",
     "type": "audio"
     "codec": "AC-3",
     "id": 2,
       "language": "dut",
     "type": "audio"
     "codec": "AC-3",
     "id": 3,
       "language": "dum",
     "type": "audio"
     "codec": "SubRip/SRT",
     "id": 4,
       "language": "dut",
     "type": "subtitles"

I'd like to insert a new line (or two?) before every occurrence of "codec" to break up the output and group things relevant items together. So to end up looking like this...

"type": "Matroska"

"codec": "MPEG-4p10/AVC/h.264", "id": 0, "language": "und", "type": "video"

"codec": "DTS", "id": 1, "language": "eng", "type": "audio" "codec": "AC-3", "id": 2, "language": "dut", "type": "audio"

"codec": "AC-3", "id": 3, "language": "dum", "type": "audio"

"codec": "SubRip/SRT", "id": 4, "language": "dut", "type": "subtitles"

Many thanks!